# Bit comparison between two files

Tags: file-comparison

I am in the process of learning bash, and I need to compare two almost identical text files (only a few bits are flipped) and output the amount of bits that are the same. In other words, I need to compare bits, not characters. Reading through the bash documentation, I came across the `comm` and `diff` commands, but they seem to compare the files line by line and not bit by bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If a single bit is flipped, a character would be different between the files. Comparing characters seems then to be the first step.

Comment: Not sure how you could find `comm` and `diff` in the bash configurations, those have nothing to do with `bash`.

Comment: As Stéphane pointed out, `comm` and `diff` are not in any way connected to or related to bash. Do you need to do this in bash, for some reason, or are you open to external tools like `comm` and `diff`? Also, what kind of files are you comparing? Text? Binary? Something else? ASCII? Unicode? Can we assume one bit per character?

Comment: Not clear on "output the amount of bits that are the same". Do you just want to **count** the bits that are the same and/or different ? Or do you want to show the *places* where the bits are different?

Comment: What is required when the files are of different lengths: are the excess bytes all counted as bit-flips (compared to zero) ?

Comment: I want to thank everyone who took the time to read and reply to my post. What I posted was a straight copy-paste of the instructions. I emailed my professor asking for further clarification but she did not reply (6 days ago). I decided to skip this question rather than answer incorrectly as you lose double the points if it is incorrect (yes, she is sadistic).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean bytes and not bits, you can use `cmp` (from `man cmp`):

> NAME
>
> cmp - compare two files byte by byte

Using these two files as an example:

```
$ cat file1
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

$ cat file2
The quick flown fax jumped over the hazy log.
```

You can do:

```
$ cmp -lb file1 file2
11 142 b    146 f
12 162 r    154 l
18 157 o    141 a
37 154 l    150 h
42 144 d    154 l
```

Alternatively, you could use `fold` to print one byte per line and pass that to `diff`:

```
$ diff <(fold -b1 file1) <(fold -b1 file2)
11,12c11,12
< b
< r
---
> f
> l
18c18
< o
---
> a
37c37
< l
---
> h
42c42
< d
---
> l
```

Comment: Terdon, I want to thank you for taking the time to read and reply to my post. I emailed my professor asking for further clarification but she did not reply (6 days ago). I decided to skip this question rather than answer incorrectly as you lose double the points if it is incorrect (yes, she is sadistic).

Answer (score 1):

Sample files:

```
$ cat tmp1 tmp2
unix and linux
uniq and lynux
```

You can use [`xxd`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/xxd/xxd.1.en.html) with `diff` as follows:

```
$ diff <(xxd -c1 tmp1) <(xxd -c1 tmp2)
4c4
< 00000003: 78  x
---
> 00000003: 71  q
11c11
< 0000000a: 69  i
---
> 0000000a: 79  y
```

With `-b` option to examine **bits**:

```
$ diff <(xxd -c1 -b tmp1) <(xxd -c1 -b tmp2)
4c4
< 00000003: 01111000  x
---
> 00000003: 01110001  q
11c11
< 0000000a: 01101001  i
---
> 0000000a: 01111001  y
```

Comment: Pandya, I want to thank you for taking the time to read and reply to my post. I emailed my professor asking for further clarification but she did not reply (6 days ago). I decided to skip this question rather than answer incorrectly as you lose double the points if it is incorrect (yes, she is sadistic).

Answer (score 1):

`perl -lne 'BEGIN{$/=\8192}; print for split "", unpack("b*", $_)'` can print each bit of a file (starting with the least significant bit in each byte) as `0` and `1` characters, one per line.

Once you have that for each file, you can paste it side-by-side with `paste -d '\0'` for instance. Then you can just count the numbers of 00 an 11 with `grep -xce 00 -e 11` to count the number of bits they have in common.

```
bits() {
  perl -lne 'BEGIN{$/=\8192}; print for split "", unpack("b*", $_)' "$1"
}
paste -d '\0' <(bits file1) <(bits file2) | grep -xce 00 -e 11
```

Comment: Stephane, I want to thank you for taking the time to read and reply to my post. I emailed my professor asking for further clarification but she did not reply (6 days ago). I decided to skip this question rather than answer incorrectly as you lose double the points if it is incorrect (yes, she is sadistic).